# Confused trying to follow least squares fitting polynomial

Tags: matrices, least-squares

I am trying to follow the steps [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPolynomial.html) but am lost on how to proceed from step 9 to actually find the values of $a_0,a_1,a_2$
I don't see what step 10 has to do with step 9

[image: Screen1]
[image: Screen2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation (10) doesn't follow from (9). Notice that (9) and (12) are identical. The article is just pointing out that you can differentiate the residual with respect to the coefficients of the interpolating polynomial to obtain (9)/(12); or you can use the Vandermonde matrix equation (10) to explicitly derive (9)/(12).

*Edit*: Suppose we're given the data

\begin{align*}
(x_{1},y_{1}) &= (-2,-2)\\
(x_{2},y_{2}) &= (-1,-2)\\
(x_{3},y_{3}) &= (1,1)\\
(x_{4},y_{4}) &= (2,3)
\end{align*}

and suppose we want to find the best quadratic polynomial fit to these points in the $2$-norm sense, i.e.,

\begin{equation*}
y = a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}x^{2}.
\end{equation*}

Then we have

\begin{equation*}
X = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2}\\
1 & x_{2} & x_{2}^{2}\\
1 & x_{3} & x_{3}^{2}\\
1 & x_{4} & x_{4}^{2}
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -2 & 4\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{y} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}\\
y_{3}\\
y_{4}
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
-2\\
-2\\
1\\
3
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}

Then we have

\begin{equation*}
X^{T}X = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
4 & 0 & 10\\
0 & 10 & 0\\
10 & 0 & 34
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

so

\begin{equation*}
\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
17/18 & 0 & -5/18\\
0 & 1/10 & 0\\
-5/18 & 0 & 1/9
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}

Then we have

\begin{equation*}
\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
17/18 & 0 & -5/18\\
0 & 1/10 & 0\\
-5/18 & 0 & 1/9
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
-2 & -1 & 1 & 2\\
4 & 1 & 1 & 4
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-1/6 & 2/3 & 2/3 & -1/6\\
-1/5 & -1/10 & 1/10 & 1/5\\
1/6 & -1/6 & -1/6 & 1/6
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

and finally,

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{a} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
a_{0}\\
a_{1}\\
a_{2}
\end{array}\right) = \left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}\mathbf{y} = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-1/6 & 2/3 & 2/3 & -1/6\\
-1/5 & -1/10 & 1/10 & 1/5\\
1/6 & -1/6 & -1/6 & 1/6
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
-2\\
-2\\
1\\
3
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
-5/6\\
13/10\\
1/3
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}

Then the least-squares quadratic polynomial fit to the data is

\begin{equation*}
y = -\frac{5}{6} + \frac{13}{10}x + \frac{1}{3}x^{2}.
\end{equation*}

Here is a plot of the data along with the quadratic least-squares fit:
[image: quadraticLeastSquaresFit]

It's pretty close! That's the beauty of the least-squares approximation. ;)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a solution to 9 that can be obtained without knowing the data?

Comment: @Kirsten I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The idea is to solve for the coefficients $a_{0},\ldots,a_{k}$ given the data $\left\{(x_{i},y_{i})\right\}_{i=1}^{n}$ so that $y = \sum_{j=0}^{k}{a_{j}x^{j}}$ is the best fitting degree $k$ polynomial to the data in the $2$-norm sense. So there aren't really any solutions to (9) that exist independent of the data. Are you asking how to actually solve for the $(a_{0},\ldots,a_{k})$?

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is what I am asking.

Comment: @Kirsten The most straightforward way to do it is by solving the normal equations, i.e., the coefficients $\mathbf{a}$ are given by $\mathbf{a} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\mathbf{y}$ where $X$ is the Vandermonde matrix in (10) (or equivalently by inverting the matrix on the left-hand side of (9)/(12)). This method has significant computational disadvantages, though.

Comment: Thank you it has been a long time since I did linear algebra. A worked example would be great.

Comment: @Kirsten I edited my answer to include a specific example. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It helps :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142792/discussion-between-kirsten-and-kandb).